# Use ansible to configure a Google Compute Instance created by ansible

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, ansible, google-compute-engine

I'm using the `gcp_compute_instance` ansible module to create an instance, basically reproducing what's in [this document](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/scenario_guides/guide_gce.html#create-an-instance). This works fine to create the instance but after the instance is created, I can't configure it with a different playbook because the instance doesn't recognize the service account as a valid ssh user. The error I get when I run the second playbook is

```
Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ansible@35.196.226.99: Permission denied (publickey).
```

I haven't found in any of the documents or tutorials on gce/ansible how to configure the ssh access to the newly created instance. All the documents kind of imply that it should just work with what you configured to actually create the instance, which is clearly not the case. What I tried was give the service account a role that has the permission `compute.instances.osAdminLogin` but there are still two pieces of information that I don't know.

1. What is the username to use to connect. My second playbook right now has `remote_user` set to the name of the service account but this is not working. How do I automatically configure this in ansible so that i can run both playbooks back to back without manual intervention?
2. How to associate the ssh key with the service account? using `gcloud compute os-login ssh-keys add` adds it to my personal account, not to the service account

Note that I can ssh into the instance using my personal account just fine, which uses the OS Login feature of GCE and my personal ssh key, but i want to run the second ansible playbook using a service account with its own ssh key, not my personal account so that I can share the whole process with other people or with a CI/CD service

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @knutole i ended up ditching os-login and just adding the ansible ssh key to the metadata service of the project. That way it applies to *all* vms in my project. so as soon as the instance is created, the ansible user can ssh in to run the next playbook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store your ansible service account SSH keys inside GCP. If you do that, your keys will be generated automatically whenever you create a VM.

In order to add keys, you can go to Compute Engine > Metadata > SSH keys

Comment: but i'm using OS Login and the documentation says
`Caution: Enabling OS Login on instances disables metadata-based SSH key configurations on those instances. `

Also, that still leaves my question #1. what username am i supposed to use??

Comment: The user you should use is your service account.  You need to add an IAM role for that account and give it permission to access your VMs.

Answer (score 3):

the scripts in the document the op is following are broken. I have just spent about a day chasing this and the problem is that the instance ends up connected to the created network rather than the project default. It then doesn't matter about os_login or keys or firewall rules you just  can't connect via either the cloud console or using SSH remotely. As a first step to remove this problem:

- remove the stanza that creates a network
- rewrite the ansible stanza that creates the instance:

```
- name: create a instance
    gcp_compute_instance:
      state: present
      name: "{{ system_name }}"
      machine_type: "{{ system_type }}"
      disks:
        - auto_delete: true
          boot: true
          source: "{{ disk }}"
      network_interfaces:
           - access_configs:
              - name: 'External NAT'
                nat_ip: "{{ address }}"
                type: 'ONE_TO_ONE_NAT'
      zone: "{{ zone }}"
      project: "{{ gcp_project }}"
      auth_kind: "{{ gcp_cred_kind }}"
      service_account_file: "{{ gcp_cred_file }}"
      scopes: 
         - "{{ gcp_scopes }}"
  register: instance
```

Of course once the vm is working and allowing ssh access. you can go back and assess whether the extra network is required and how to use it.

Comment: this should have been accepted answer: bumped into the same issue, network and firewall rules will be inherited from the project.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [document](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/scenario_guides/guide_gce.html#credentials) you are mentioning, you can use either Service account with the roles required to perform the operation or an account associated to the machine (GCE) which also is a [service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts#types_of_service_accounts).

You can achieve this by [creating a service account.](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#creating_a_service_account) and [generating a JSON key](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys#creating_service_account_keys) for this.